# Running an application in from a Jar dependency

Tags: java

I am trying to execute a java command in my method that will launch my JavaFX jar application using a spring profile (stub). 
The jar is a dependency of my project located in the *\dir\dependency*. 
The profile is located in the app.yaml.

I am using the following command:

```
String buildfolder = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String javahome = envmap.get("JAVA_HOME")+"\\jre"; 
process = driver.getApplications().run(javahome + 
        "\\bin\\javaw.exe",
        "-Xms512m " +
                "-Xmx2024m " +
                "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC " +
                "-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode " +
                "-verbose:gc " +
                "-classpath ./* " +
                "-Dspring.profiles.active=stub " +
                "-Dspring.config.location=classpath:conf/app.yaml " +
                "-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures " +
                "-XX:+FlightRecorder " +
                "-Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.yaml " +
                "au.com.nab.fx.nova.app.NovaUIDriver",
        buildfolder + "\\dir\\dependency");
```

However, before the application is ran, I get the following error:

> The application '"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\bin\javaw.exe"' (PID 15752) exited with code 1 before the test engine could access it.

Is there something obvious wrong with my command? 
Should I use a different type of command to do this instead of javaw.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue. I did the following.

1. Used Java command to execute the above (instead of javaw) in a command prompt.
2. I noticed the I got "main *class could not be loaded*. I assumed it was due to the main *class not being found*. However, that was not the case. The *main class could not be loaded* was due to some dependencies missing.
3. I manually copied the dependencies into the appropriate directory and everything worked.